# Powershell Excel - Copy from Named Range

Tags: excel, powershell, com, named-ranges

Struggling to get a grasp of automating inserting data in to Excel with Powershell.  So far I have managed to get columns with the correct date inserted in to sheets that match our cluster names.  I am now hoping to pick values from a named range in an existing spreadsheet and then past the values in to a cell.

I have been able to find lots of pieces around creating a range and naming it but nothing that I can really understand to help me address an existing range.  My COM understanding is limited but I am slowly piecing bit together - suspect I am missing something fundamental.

I thought I was close with the following:

```
[void]$SrcWorkSheet.Range("ClusterName",11).Copy()
```

But this seems to return an error that suggests backward compatability woth 2007 is causing the issue.

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

I am eventually hoping to replace "ClusterName" with a variable I am looping through so it is repeateable across multiple sheets.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that "11" in Range("ClusterName",11)? If you want to select your named range you should just get it by Range("ClusterName")

Comment: apologies, was trying to select the 11th row of the named range, I suppose similar to the =INDEX() formula in excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to copy just the 11th row in your range,

```
$SrcWorkSheet.Range("ClusterName").Rows(11).Copy()
```

Comment: Ah, I get it now.  Thanks very much, worked like a charm